# JMAP Docker doesn't start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jmap

I am trying to run a JMAP-perl docker, but when I docker compose it, I get this error :
Attaching to jmap

```
jmap    | Starting nginx: nginx.
jmap    | Can't locate Encode/IMAPUTF7.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/jmap/jmap-perl /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /home/jmap/jmap-perl/JMAP/ImapDB.pm line 17.
jmap    | BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/jmap/jmap-perl/JMAP/ImapDB.pm line 17.
jmap    | Compilation failed in require at (eval 334) line 2.
jmap    |   ...propagated at /usr/share/perl/5.14/base.pm line 93.
jmap    | BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/jmap/jmap-perl/JMAP/GmailDB.pm line 8.
jmap    | Compilation failed in require at ./bin/apiendpoint.pl line 23.
jmap    | BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./bin/apiendpoint.pl line 23.
jmap exited with code 2
```

Here is my Docker-Compose.yml :

```
version: '2'

services:
  jmap:
    image: rpignolet/jmap-perl:latest
    container_name: jmap
    restart: on-failure:5
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 50m
    ports:
      - "41054:41054"
    volumes:
      - jmap:/root/jmap-perl
    networks:
        - elasticsearch_esnet

networks:
    elasticsearch_esnet:
        external: true

volumes:
  jmap:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /home/jmap
```

I am really new on Docker, so I would like to know if someone could help me!